# Which is the best option to select - Don't Correlate or Automatically Correlate? in Webload(Radview) recording

Tags: javascript, webloadui

I am new to Webload Testing and trying to perform load testing using Webload (Radview free version) Tool.Once the recording is complete in IDE, which option is advisable to select Don't Correlate or Automatically Correlate? . I had selected both and tested.

When I try Don't correlate - I get error message saying " 500 Internal Server Error Requested url : in main _agenda at line 74

When I try Automatically Correlate - It works fine.

This is the code without correlation

```
wlGlobals.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.17763"
wlGlobals.AcceptLanguage = "en-GB"
wlHttp.Header["Referer"] = "https://gmail/LoginPage" // Changed url here for security purpose
wlHttp.FormdataEncodingType = 5
wlHttp.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
wlHttp.FormData["__EVENTTARGET"] = "$WL$EMPTY$STRING$"
wlHttp.FormData["__EVENTARGUMENT"] = "$WL$EMPTY$STRING$"
wlTemporary = "B0B5X6bftN++BRK3vVaj2xUoVv/r9eUZR92YU0OoY42SvAdsqgU2exM428y1DY9CwyUZnpMJsjfUaY8oHSV5GRXsOz+W6nmRB/XDGcWhXbsfe7QUxcc7KVEfVtnEIEXMoaVJCSq2LxaENYBbIIn5BCMZABPbr/9Y3+/kbHsUBYFaEmrfyxXbgOvw32oFjh60UkomTCk4x6SqF8HwVNfL/ayOErj+W328j0nfX0uc6gxBgfop0yPg/FmD4JmtvM0tdxMiUlMLIY/z54bbcKMp31SXcDBz6zJ+EVftmB16gM/iBjMcAsUjKXoUyB+rbf8oN2RxJToEfdxGxdgfVa4W6v7iQyCieAN6rZJBrhEjdsXSn18yYDU+qVdtU+Xf/jyMa6ReR0MEJcxvQEmRe"
        + "JUVAGU0NCycInzI3wGiTfJlTWc/JSFwQzkt/tEPaAQCR2jGHmVppbOA/9XCXoDyUviiQ2CQkapXIrw+OQPngmAxmb+pRV9133ddnJ8SZXS/3jmEoGdA4RGiaYiyQCl/rpNmo240q672VUo5DN2rV1HJrsCUaseIBZZh4Vj9g2KMJZfHgUj8Vz4zuN72u7vF0nfeedecFibwMjkoFd/eqAA0OGaxYslxZPJYuMmBD74H6TLS7OSX3Y9lS8xDzcI1jiY2Ft7FlTG8rDkTQ6BPxfYqaww+n6+tP4nwViX9/koWINPSQhk938WzYdZ4Zo3rEUnrhKMkABhZcoGER593JyHm+MacTjbG38RH9tb7PV8lzvBbJPj+x2xI1HzUWDNZIIB8sucTndjGo6D53"
        + "0x7LZiJ9azIgVTq/VaNE/ClnTy5Sh+/JVALoViZ04gw+moUAWLk9Rz34tJLtgmUBULMDmQ8D7AYF0eDOfMZDzvECOvmsCMSGKqAHKjgJ5/gmP7jcLldyumqwWUPfxeEpQv0EaEaJGKLyrnk/3Me3yvJgbQgU7q6WLYZvk7Sy4rZ40iUcfLeRCUTwBoXDxs3L03CYHh1HSzItIwfPPUwwGUnEk/Y1/v0OMgr6FS9Al2WrXKBPdllJZF2c+Pw9kQA/buBYRyLn0NaGppRVRunZ8/mTbaxdSdtd2zoeAeYV5wIvl5K8gmP0d9jygJ8kH5UBZ4dcT/c2lNJDL/nigFFBb8IHWlxCpflJji9i4bpN0lKLb3KBroCyKzmQhac3MYlFQxoUmTwwIRXjIvvy"
        + "lzyRbDbNQztK7ALOE3eXo7ABAb1gUSbZ84WjSLzntNooXb6khcZgzzvyifqmN2VvNnWBE7kz6/S114rZSHt03Hi9pIOT9qZw4deLeIuL5LjChF/usa+VAkm9G397nQdvYApLyyrUMIqad2Trj6cwY986RYRLvxNb2v1z109WwZyR4LfJMWXdP+c2e3D2H/SUVe67TTk3b4t5QXWTSVsBFs76vhukIHAXIt6PrvBWwA8Kc0QaiqV00M/b84d8BgFWtNbEBTzqTKlGb/0+5+oZntgiWj1FgYqFRfDUoKsAkqfGhefW2pOXRejvAdmviObIIGxgSLKDoq3t9KQgmKupoPdCP8O1aaIKAHBiOt7fWZJzCKN31UYkUp2X+sloPAl4eZ0OLrLzPRnsa3qI"
        + "IINVcLPNeQzeyQ1AnWezIkq9fULB55W22opwXkC0wmr4/k4nYbnbu4s9/uxZJvUP7p73quzZ5CTQ3U9Fn8p2ONr5RgVeMtbAatNBhlzf2gOwX1HfvbQpC6pKJ3VdN0SjjJqze6Z4NhnCfUqEZCmBx2cvIUMs9Kg6kZafHFrSdn/gCWZxZRAZJElp6UPbfmkJjS6XnoCi8RRqIe1AML4XxZr9+7QhPcsRc8EKiBED0vPd19UevVp1xLrD0R9zXNKCJHzDHRNf82bbKdTO7dIRaFtVHE2e61j5QrKp5LkEbjGOoXqR9Ckwo/lV3P9RJA5cSFEN8jjj1pJNbKl0j+ZIxWMQpTiL1qEA3gqQFATZhMizxk3/n0JEk+7Aa2DByn4Huon65X0nC+TSeacJ"
        + "BPmNXxWhNc8/pm0fE/IuMcJxHomdr5NsBY4Lq7Y6RYphw+d9iTSZWVmxSPY18+DRwkHAw=="

wlHttp.FormData["__VIEWSTATE"] = wlTemporary
wlHttp.FormData["__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"] = "0F9F611E"
wlHttp.FormData["__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED"] = "$WL$EMPTY$STRING$"
wlHttp.FormData["__EVENTVALIDATION"] = "ArmKA5fUCSWyuG82fQTS/7t4lH/qrrjI3WEWcdtyTHSVCkwrKO1JJjm+/y79FOYP+An3W2pAlVvVwmUex7U5phHJ0/t2fuxrxkMQ1xwrf6JyRNKeElb2ty8prKE68VDxUzZHOTdZjJiWPAB5f+/KlDF9JkGXzlYY5p0I9NWK0PM83bGYEDjFWjGKUTFM5Th/Z+zQKcyQk5aj+unE9BP6RQzjsy0qYqR2X5Q4pkIu0tL5z50ZR14RAQBQSAhfIt4f"
wlHttp.FormData["ctl00$maincontent$ControlLogin1$email_address"] = "test@gmail.com"
wlHttp.FormData["ctl00$maincontent$ControlLogin1$password"] = "Test123"
wlHttp.FormData["DocumentID"] = "LoginPage"
wlCookie.Set("_ga", "GA1.2.1957913211.1610361754", "gmail.com", "/", "", 
"");
wlCookie.Set("_gat_gtag_UA_00000000_0", "1", "gmail.com", "/", "", "");
wlCookie.Set("_gid", "GA1.2.632442093.1610361754", "gmail.com", "/", "", 
"");
wlHttp.Post("https://gmail.com/LoginPage")// Changed url for security purpose - line no 74 where I am getting error
```

Answer (score 1):

You should almost always want to 'automatically correlate'. You'd only want to not correlate if you plan to run correlation later (for example, if you want to save the file first).

Correlation will replace the dynamic values for you - in your case, the '__VIEWSTATE' field - without it, you would send a stale value that will be rejected by the server.

Comment: Thank you. How do I get those value from the browser during execution? Ex : when I checked,  __VIEWSTATE value is <input name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" type="hidden" value="tvHyuPlH2Dtct" Tried something like this ,but myMatch is returning null  var State=null;
    var namepattern = /\<input name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" type="hidden" value = \"(.*)\" \>/;
 var myMatch = namepattern.exec(document.wlSource);
 InfoMessage("mymatch is:" +myMatch);
 if (myMatch!=null)
        State=myMatch[1];
 return State;